# $G$-CW complex structure of certain G-space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-cohomology, equivariant-homotopy

Let $G$ be a finite group  and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ . Let us denote $X= G/H \ast G/H \ast \cdots \ast G/H $($k$ times).Where $\ast$ denotes the topological join operation. My question are as follows:

Question 1:  What should be a $G$-CW complex structure of $X$?

**Edit** Question 2 : How to calculate the integer graded Bredon cohomology of $X$ with a constant coefficient system?

Any hint or references will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The join of discrete sets is naturally a simplicial complex, hence a CW complex. The $G$-action on $G/H$ induces a diagonal $G$-action on $X$, under which it becomes a $G$-CW complex.

Comment: @MarkGrant: I understand your point. But I want to calculate the integer graded Bredon cohomology of $X$ with a constant coefficient system.

Comment: @Surojit so you complain that Mark Grant didn't answer a question you didn't pose? I think Mark's answer does answer your question. Maybe you should open a new thread if you have a new question.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Sorry Sir. I don't want to mean this.